# Basis for a Cartesian Product of Two Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am presently reading about the product topology in Munkres' book on Topology. However, this theorem has halted my reading:

> Theorem 15.1. If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology on $X$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for a topology on $Y$, then the collection
>
> $\mathcal{D} = \{B \times C ~|~ B, \in \mathcal{B}, C \in \mathcal{C}\}$
>
> is a basis for the topology on $X \times Y$.

My question is, for *what* topology on $X \times Y$; would it be the product topology? The definite article "the" is causing some confusion for me.

Comment: Perhaps they use the definite article because a basis can only generate one topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it refers to the product topology. In the context of basic topology, if $X,Y$ are spaces then $X \times Y$ always has the product topology, unless specified otherwise. That is what makes it a product of spaces, instead of just a product of the underlying sets. In this particular case, you can of course also prove for yourself that the topology generated by the given basis is the product topology.

Similarly, $X \sqcup Y$ always has the topology of $X$ and $Y$, and a subset always has the subset topology, unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct it should more accurately say "a" topology. In this case the motivation is that the topology generated by this basis is called the product topology and is in some sense the natural topology to to consider on the Cartesian product.